# Macports refuses to install python 2.7.6.0

Tags: macos, python, macports, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to upgrade various programs I have installed with MacPorts. Unfortunately, python refuses to upgrade:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for python27
--->  Configuring python27
Error: Failed to configure python27, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/work/Python-2.7.6/config.log
Error: org.macports.configure for port python27 returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port python27 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

The `main.log` file just has the output from `./configure`, which isn't of any help, except it says that IPV6 support was not found. However, the `config.log` has this bit:

```
configure:11358: checking for getaddrinfo
configure:11376: /usr/bin/clang -o conftest -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Os -fwrapv -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/db46 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -isysroot / -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -L/opt/local/lib/db46 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 conftest.c -ldl  >&5
conftest.c:221:10: fatal error: 'sys/types.h' file not found
#include <sys/types.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

The failed program is:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
getaddrinfo(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  ;
  return 0;
}
```

And this failed to compile because `sys/types.h` wasn't found, instead of `getaddrinfo` not existing. And when I pasted this program into a file, the C compiler succeeded in compiling it.

What is happening? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a current version of MacPorts? They've been providing binary packages for quite some time now. I'd start by upgrading, then uninstalling python27 and then re-installing.

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port -f uninstall python27
sudo port clean python
sudo port install python
sudo port -uc upgrade outdated
```

I just did this on my install, and it installed the binary package, no compilation needed.

As to the actual error you're getting, I'd check that the XCode CLI tools are all installed; `ls -lah /usr/include/sys/types.h` should give you a file. If not, try `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: for some reason, my system doesn't have a `/usr/include` directory

Comment: Make sure you've installed XCode, and then install the CLI tools by running `xcode-select --install` from Terminal.

Comment: are you sure it isn't different for Mavericks?

Comment: Xcode finds the file just fine

Comment: My Mavericks system has the standard C header files in /usr/include and many many more. I'm just guessing that these are installed as part of XCode and/or the command line tools.

Comment: I'm trying `xcode-select install`, things are looking promising

Comment: it worked! Properly!

Comment: well, yes, but what I did isn't in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, edited to add the command to install CLI tools.